# Is there exist a linear map $T:\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R^3}$ such that $Range(T)=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)∈ \mathbb{R}:x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 0\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there exist a linear map $T:\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R^3}$ such that

$Range(T)=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)∈ \mathbb{R}:x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 0\}$?

I do not understand what is actually I have to do here.I think it is not enough to show that $Range(T)$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$.Somebody please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this linear transformation:
$$T(x,y)=(x,y,-x-y)\quad?$$

**Added** The set $\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in \mathbb{R}^3:x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 0\}$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ since it's the kernel of the linear form 
$$(x,y,z)\mapsto x+y+z$$
hence this set is a hyperplan of $\Bbb R^3$ and its dimension is $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Your task is to find (or die trying) a linear map $T\colon \mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^3$ such that

- for each poitn in $\mathbb R^2$, its image point $(x_1,x_2,x3)$ fulfills $x_1+x_2+x_3=0$
- every point $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in \mathbb R^3$ with $x_1+x_2+x_3$ is $T(u_1,u_2)$ for some point $(u_1,u_2)\in\mathbb R^2$.